# Is there an efficient way to get an array of objects from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building an app and I have an array of objects. The objects have a key where the value is an array of objects with key value pairs. I would like to convert this array into an array of just objects

My first array looks like this:

```
const firstArray = [
  {
    amount: 343,
    code: "RCU8YI0NKS",
    items: [
      {
        productOne: "crust",
        quantity: 2.2,
      },
      {
        productTwo: "dust",
        quantity: 34,
      },
    ],
    user_id: "wewewefwOHG22323kj",
  },
  {
    amount: 343,
    code: "RCU8YI0NKS",
    items: [
      {
        productTwo: "dust",
        quantity: 32,
      },
      {
        productThree: "must",
        quantity: 34,
      },
    ],
    user_id: "m2LgLRD9MEVNAX56JTpRYDkOOjd2",
  },
];
```

I would like it to look like this array:

```
const secondArray = [
  {
    amount: 343,
    code: "RCU8YI0NKS",
    crust: 2.2,
    dust: 34,
    user_id: "wewewefwOHG22323kj",
  },
  {
    amount: 343,
    code: "RCU8YI0NKS",
    dust: 32,
    must: 34,
    user_id: "m2LgLRD9MEVNAX56JTpRYDkOOjd2",
  },
];
```

If anyone knows how to do this, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: May you share what you've tried? Add a [mcve] to the question

Comment: why do we need to search for the correct property on the items? why ain't this consistent? are you encoding additional information in that propertyName? then you might be better off with a third property on the item instead of a dynamic shape. Like: `{ name: "dust", quantity: 32, whateverThisIs: "productTwo" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just have to turn the `items` into key value pairs and add them to the object:

```js
const flatten = arr => arr.map(({items, ...obj}) => items.reduce((agg, {quantity, ...rest}) => (agg[Object.values(rest)[0]] = quantity, agg), obj))

const firstArray = [
  {
    amount: 343,
    code: "RCU8YI0NKS",
    items: [
      {productOne: "crust", quantity: 2.2,},
      {productTwo: "dust", quantity: 34,},
    ],
    user_id: "wewewefwOHG22323kj",
  },
  {
    amount: 343,
    code: "RCU8YI0NKS",
    items: [
      {productTwo: "dust", quantity: 32,},
      {productThree: "must", quantity: 34,},
    ],
    user_id: "m2LgLRD9MEVNAX56JTpRYDkOOjd2",
  },
];

console.log(flatten(firstArray))
```

Comment: you can simplify `Object.assign(obj, items.reduce(..., {}))` to just `items.reduce(..., obj)`

Answer (score 2):

I can't see other way to do it without scanning all arrays, except if there's a kind of pattern I didn't see in the data.

The reduce function should do the job :

```js
function reduce(arr) {
  return arr.map(e => {
    // If you need to not modify original data
    const o = Object.assign({}, e);
    // Otherwise use e directly
    
    for(let item of e.items) {
       let q, name;
       
       for(let p in item) {
          if(p === "quantity") {
            q = item[p];
          } else {
            name = item[p];
          }
       }
       
       o[name] = q;
    }
    
    delete o.items;
    
    return o;
  });
}

const firstArray = [
  {
    amount: 343,
    code: "RCU8YI0NKS",
    items: [
      {
        productOne: "crust",
        quantity: 2.2,
      },
      {
        productTwo: "dust",
        quantity: 34,
      },
    ],
    user_id: "wewewefwOHG22323kj",
  },
  {
    amount: 343,
    code: "RCU8YI0NKS",
    items: [
      {
        productTwo: "dust",
        quantity: 32,
      },
      {
        productThree: "must",
        quantity: 34,
      },
    ],
    user_id: "m2LgLRD9MEVNAX56JTpRYDkOOjd2",
  },
];

console.log(reduce(firstArray));
```